# stop tomcat web application gracefully shutdown all servlet connections

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, servlets

We want to create a backup of our db but need to know that all connections are closed behind our web application.

So if I send a stop to the specific web application in Tomcat, will it wait and gracefully shutdown all jobs/processes that are behind it (connections to the H2 DB) and also not accept any incoming request anymore ?

Comment: Are you stopping the webapp, or are you stopping the entire Tomcat server?

Comment: the question clearly says "So if I send a stop to the **specific** web application in Tomcat". So he is stopping a webapp and not the entire server.

Comment: Indeed I am stopping a webapp and not the entire Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat does not terminate any connections that you may have open to your database: you will have to terminate these yourself. Try using a `ServletContextListener` to shut-down all your database connections when your webapp is shutting down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christopher, this is very helpful